# Why don't these numbers add in Xcode Debugger?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, debugging

I'm using the Xcode debugger, and these numbers don't seem to add. I was curious as to why :

```
(lldb) p height
(CGFloat) $R0 = 2.1815627849240522E-314 
(lldb) p frame.size
(CGSize) $R1 = (width = 375, height = 1000)
(lldb) p frame.size.height
(CGFloat) $R2 = 1000
(lldb) p height + frame.size.height
(CGFloat) $R3 = 1000
```

I have 3 questions about this..

1. What is `2.1815627849240522E-314` ? What kind of number is that?
2. Is it possible to instantiate temporary variables in debugger like you would in Ruby console, Chrome console etc.? For example, `let temp_x = 4` ?
3. Why does my `$R3` return 1000 and not.. something bigger?

Comment: can you please add some code that you are trying to Debug

Comment: @NitinGohel I'm not entirely sure what more you would need. `frame = self.tableView`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`2.1815627849240522E-314` is essentially zero. `1000 + 0 = 1000`.

Floating point numbers have two parts - mantissa and exponent (position of the decimal point). `e-341` means "move the decimal point 341 places to the right"

Adding `1000` to that very very small number creates a number that would be equal

```
1000.000...(> 300 zeros here)...2181567849240522
```

Even `double` mantissa can't represent numbers like this (`double` can represent up to 17 decimal digits) so it takes only the more important numbers in the beginning.

I encourage you to read through [What Every Programmer Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://floating-point-gui.de/)

Comment: @user3441734 It's a way to represent `0.0...(312 zeros)..21815627849240522`, which is a number that comes from small rounding errors but essentially there is no measurable difference from zero.

Comment: the question is why xcode print this. the value is NOT representable as CGFloat

Comment: @user3441734 why so? It can be definitely represented in `double` precision (64 bits) which is what `CGFloat` usually stands for.

Comment: height is most likely an uninitialised variable. So careful, running the same code again you might get an entirely different value. Changing one completely unrelated line of code could change it. @user3441734: CGFloat is 32 bit on 32 bit systems, 64 bit on 64 bit systems.

Comment: @gnasher729 yes, it is clear, i see Float even though CGFloat is there :-)